How to prove that "i & (i - 1) == 0" means "i is the power of 2"
If we know beforehand that i must be something like 10...0, it's not hard to imagine. 
But how to mathematically prove that i & (i - 1) == 0 is sufficient to say i is the power of 2, at lease for positive integer? 
You can find some explanations of this expression in How to check if a number is a power of 2 But I don't think an explanation is congruent with a mathematical proof.

Consider i in binary. When would the leftmost "1" become "0" after & with i - 1?

@interjay good point. Why not write this as an answer

This question is similar to: How to check if a number is a power of 2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@teapot418 I saw that and then I asked this question. In my question, I want a proof and I've addressed it clearly. If you find any answer from that link as a mathematical proof instead of explanation, please paste the link to an answer. (FYI, What is a mathematical proof?)

@ripfreeworld I didn't downvote, but I would assume that that the downvotes were because this isn't a programming question. It's a math question and, if anywhere, it belongs on one of the math sites. This is also the reason that it was closed.

With i & (i - 1) == 0 means "i is the power of 2" has special programming considerations when i is unsigned and others when i is signed. VTRO.

"... at lease for positive integer?" I assume that you exclude zero from being "positive" !? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/is-zero-positive-or-negative

Depends on operator precedence. In e.g. C it's wrong.

@4386427 Zero is not a power of 2, so there's really no need to extend the proof to zero, but 0 & (0 - 1) ~= 0, so really it works anyway. As for operator precedence, I had assumed, since there was no language tagged, that this was pseudo-code. I mean, it certainly isn't valid Lisp or Prolog code.

If you want a proof, ask in a math site, not in a programming site.

Technically, the statement is not correct, in case of i is a signed int it should be

i & (i - 1) == 0 if and only if i is a power of 2 or 0

The proof is easy:
If i is power of 2, then it can be represented as 1000...000 (binary)
and we have
  1000...000 - i is a power of 2 
  0111...111 - i - 1
  ----------
  0000...000 = 0

If i is 0 then we have
          0 - i = 0
  111...111 -1 (2 complement)
  ---------
          0

If i is not a power of 2 or 0 then it has at least two bits set, let's take leftmost and rightmost of them:
  i = 1?..?10...0
      ^    ^ rightmost 1
      leftmost 1

and we have the leftmost bit ever set:
  1?..?10...0 - i
  1?..?01...1 - i - 1 
  -----------
  1?..?00...0 > 0


I think your first diagram is incorrect, the i - 1 value should end in 111.

@Mark Ransom: Thank you! You are quite right - it should be all 1 except for the leftmost bit. I've edited the answer.

"i & (i - 1) == 0 if and only if i is a power of 2 or 0" is not complete in C.  It is UB when i -1 overflows.

We are now in the C23 era, so "i & (i - 1) == 0 if and only if i is a power of 2 or 0" falling for non-2's compliment" is no longer a concern.  Even so, OP did not specify a signed type, so adding an unsigned analysis is deserved.

To make a mathematical proof, prerequisites must be in place first.
The question is not fully clear about that. As there is no language tag, it's not clear what i & (i - 1) == 0 is doing - nor how it's evaluated.
It kind of look like C code but in C this statement won't return TRUE if and only if i is a power of 2. So it can't be C code.
So before making a mathematical proof, let's make the prerequisites clear:

() has highest precedence
& has higher precedence than ==
& is bitwise boolean AND operator
- is subtraction
== is relational equal
i is an unsigned number with representation an-12n-1 + ... + a121 + a020 where ak is either 0 or 1  and n is the number of bits.

As zero is not a power of 2, the statement we want to prove is:
For any non-zero value of i, the expression i & (i - 1) == 0 is TRUE if and only if i is a power of 2
With the number format described above a number is a power of 2 if and only if exactly one ak is 1 and all other are 0.
As i is non-zero, we know that at least one bit will be 1. So let's look at an i value where ak is the least significant bit being 1. It will look like:
i : an-12n-1 + ... + ak+12k+1 + 1 * 2k + 0 * 2k-1 + ... + 0 * 20
Subtraction of 1 will clear ak and set all the lower bits to 1. It will look like:
i-1 : an-12n-1 + ... + ak+12k+1 + 0 * 2k + 1 * 2k-1 + ... + 1 * 20
Doing the bitwise AND will then look like:
i & (i-1) : an-12n-1 + ... + ak+12k+1 + 0 * 2k + 0 * 2k-1 + ... + 0 * 20
which is the same as just:
i & (i-1) : an-12n-1 + ... + ak+12k+1
A number where the k'th bit and all lower bits are zero. This number will be equal to zero if and only if an-1, an-2, ..., ak+1 are all zero.
In other words, if i & (i-1) == 0 is TRUE (and i is non-zero), we know the only non-zero bit in i is ak. Thereby it proves that i is a power of 2.

you are using i in two different roles. it is confusing.

@WillNess Fair. Answer updated.
